# How to Obfuscate an Ionic Capacitor Application?

Tags: java, android, security, ionic-framework

I'm wondering if there's a way to obfuscate an ionic capacitor application? All the posts I've seen are with Cordova but there is not much out there for capacitor.

I guess I am more interested in obfuscating the java code as it seems easy enough to use JSscrambler for obfuscating the JS code.

Our app is running Capacitor V3 and has some Cordova plugins given we recently migrated to Capacitor.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but what about [Proguard](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#using-proguard), from the Capacitor docs?